# Laravel how to show detail in jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, modal-dialog

I found some problem on my project, when i click edit, the modal show with value from database, but when i clicked show/details, it won't appear anything. im using ajax jquery, can someone help ?

Im using Route Resource on this route

this is HTML code

```
             <div class="modal fade" id="ajax-modal" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                          <h4 class="modal-title" id="userShowModal"></h4>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                          <form id="userForm" name="userForm" class="form-horizontal">
                             <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id">

                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nama</label>
                                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nama" name="nama"  maxlength="50" disabled value="">
                                  </div>
                              </div>
               
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                                      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="kategori" name="kategori" placeholder="Enter Email" value="" disabled>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </form>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

this is my Javascript code

```
   //Edit Data
    $('body').on('click', '.edit-post', function () {
        var data_id = $(this).data('id');
        $.get('narasumber/' + data_id + '/edit', function (data) {
            $('#modal-judul').html("Edit Narasumber");
            $('#tombol-simpan').val("edit-post");
            $('#tambah-edit-modal').modal('show');

            $('#id').val(data.id);
            $('#nama').val(data.nama);
            $('#kategori').val(data.kategori);
            $('#nomorhp').val(data.nomorhp);
            $('#email').val(data.email);
            $('#jk').val(data.jk);
            $('#pendidikan').val(data.pendidikan);
            $('#pekerjaan').val(data.pekerjaan);
            $('#kota').val(data.kota);
            $('#provinsi').val(data.provinsi);
        })
    });
    //Detail data
    $('body').on('click', '.detail-narasumber', function () {
        data_id = $(this).data('id');
        $.get('narasumber/' + data_id, function (data) {
            $('#userShowModal').html("User Details");
            $('#ajax-modal').modal('show');
            
            $('#id').html(data.id);
            $('#nama').html(data.nama);
            $('#nomorhp').html(data.nomorhp);
            $('#email').html(data.email);
            $('#jk').html(data.jk);
            $('#pendidikan').html(data.pendidikan);
            $('#pekerjaan').html(data.pekerjaan);
            $('#kota').html(data.kota);
            $('#provinsi').html(data.provinsi);
        })
    });
```

and this is Controller laravel

```
 public function show($id)
    {
        $where =  array('id' => $id);
            $post  = narasumber::where($where)->find($id);
    
        return response()->json($post);
    }

    
    public function edit($id)
    {
    $where = array('id' => $id);
            $post  = narasumber::where($where)->first();
        
            return response()->json($post);
    }
```

In this case i just want to show details from my data on table

Comment: You don't appear to have an element with a class of `.detail-narasumber` yet you are listening to a click on it

Comment: soo where do i have to appear an element on that code?